# css - how to handle collapse border in Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a tab.
When I switch the tab, the active item will have black border, while the inactive one will have grey border.

But I find the border overlap for all 2 items like below
[image]

The overlap border should be black only.

How to fix it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import Tab from "./Tab";

import { useState } from "react";

const options = [
  { id: "1", label: "First" },
  { id: "2", label: "Second" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Tab
        options={options}
        selectedOption={selectedOption}
        setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Tab.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

function Tab(props) {
  const { options, selectedOption, setSelectedOption } = props;
  return (
    <div className="tab">
      {options &&
        options.map((option) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={
                "tab__item " +
                (selectedOption === option.id ? "tab__item--active" : "")
              }
              key={option.id}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedOption(option.id);
              }}
            >
              {option.label}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tab;
```

styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
}
.tab .tab__item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
}

.tab .tab__item--active {
  border: 1px solid #3c434a;
}

.tab .tab__item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sound-t312f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Raptor posted now

Comment: You should post the resultant HTML & CSS instead of ReactJS codes, as this is obviously a HTML & CSS problem.

Comment: And the `border-collapse` CSS property is useful for your scenario: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: @Raptor I tried to add in flex-container and flex-item but both not working

Comment: It's not clear what you want. To have grey border there or not to overlap?

Comment: @Azu the overlap border should be black

Comment: But the overlaping border is black now! You don't want the borders to overlap?

Comment: @Azu I want to remove the overlap grey border because I can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need just to manipulate the css *border* properties. In this case `border-left` and `border-right`. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-breeze-0yd5j?file=/src/styles.css:59-737)

**CSS**

```
.tab {
  display: flex;
}
.tab .tab__item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
}

.tab__item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
}

.tab__item:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
  border-right: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
}

.tab__item--active:first-child {
  border: 1px solid #3c434a;
}
.tab__item--active:first-child ~ .tab__item:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tab__item--active:last-child {
  border: 1px solid #3c434a;
}

.tab .tab__item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### To achieve the required behavior we need to render styles conditionally

1. If overlapping is the problem we can simply add a margin.

   ```
     .tab .tab__item {
       flex: 1 1 0;
       border: 1px solid #c3c4c7;
       margin: 0.1rem;
       padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
     }
   ```
2. If you don't want to give a margin. You can do something like this.

   - Create a function getInactiveClass
   - If no tab is selected just return "" as before
   - Apply 3 different styles based on the selectedTab to remove border-right/border-left
   - If selectedTab has a tab on its left we remove border-right
   - If selectedTab has a tab on its right we remove border-left
   - Note: Both borders would be removed if selectedTab is in between 2 tabs

> ```
>   const getInactiveClass = (key) => {
>     const index = options.findIndex((item) => item.id === selectedOption);
>     if (!selectedOption) return "";
>
>     if (key === index - 1) {
>       return "tab__item--inactive-right";
>     }
>
>     if (key === index + 1) {
>       return "tab__item--inactive-left";
>     }
>   };
> ```

---

[View Complete code snippet on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-5-hrpir?file=/src/Tab.jsx)